# Excel VBA - Comparing interlaced column with non-interlaced column

Tags: vba, excel

I have two sheets where I am trying to check to make sure one column has the same values as the other column on the other sheet.

On one sheet, the values are interlaced with names on the same column. Whilst on the other sheet the values are on a single column by themselves.

```
Sheet1                Sheet2

                      Column1 Column 2
Column1               Name1   rate1
Name1                 Name2   rate2
rate1                 Name3   rate3
Name2
rate2
Name3
rate3
```

I want Excel to be able to look at `rate1` in `Sheet1` and see if it matches `rate1` in `Sheet2` and if there is a difference, highlight the cell red in `Sheet2`. If the rate in `Sheet1` is "N/A", leave it alone and don't highlight red.

I'm having trouble with reading from the correct cells and getting it to skip the names in `Sheet1`.

Here is my code: *(It's messy...)*

```
Sub ratetest()
    Dim calc As Double
    Dim rate As Double
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet: Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
    Dim a As Integer
    Dim b As Integer

    'rate = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(a, 9)
    'calc = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(b, 4)

    a = 13
    b = 2

    For a = 13 To ws1.Range("I45").End(xlUp).Row Step 2
        For b = 2 To ws1.Range("D17").End(xlUp).Row
            If ws1.Cells(a, 9) <> ws2.Cells(b, 4) Or ws1.Cells(a, 9) <> "N/A" Then
                ' do nothing...
            Else
                With Selection.Interior
                    .Pattern = xlSolid
                    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                    .Color = 255
                    .TintAndShade = 0
                    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
                End With
            End If
        Next b
    Next a
End Sub
```

Comment: 1. Stack Overflow is not a Code for me site.  2. There is no question.  3. Why not use Conditional Formatting?

Comment: I understand, I have code but it is way off. The question being where to go with an IF Then (If I put the code up then maybe it would make sense where the question would come up). And 3. This is only part of the grand scheme of what I want done. Eventually this is going to be performed on multiple columns and multiple different workbooks.

Comment: Your `If` statement goes straight into `Then`...are you missing a line? Also, put the `With Selection.Interior` under the `Else` line, not next to it with a colon.

Comment: When the criteria is met (both values match), I want nothing to happen and just move onto the next pair. When I hit run now, nothing happens. No error but I remain on the module screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will highlight in red all cells on Sheet2-Col D not found on Sheet1-Col I:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub RateTest1()
    Const COLUMN_1 = "I", WS1_START = 12
    Const COLUMN_2 = "D", WS2_START = 2
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, col1 As Variant, col2 As Variant, tr As Long
    Dim max1 As Long, max2 As Long, r1 As Long, r2 As Long, red As Long, found As Boolean
    Dim miss As Range

    tr = Rows.Count:                         red = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1"): max1 = ws1.Cells(tr, COLUMN_1).End(xlUp).Row
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2"): max2 = ws2.Cells(tr, COLUMN_2).End(xlUp).Row

    col1 = ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(1, COLUMN_1), ws1.Cells(max1, COLUMN_1))
    col2 = ws2.Range(ws2.Cells(1, COLUMN_2), ws2.Cells(max2, COLUMN_2))

    For r2 = WS2_START To max2              'check each value on sheet 2, col D
        For r1 = WS1_START To max1 Step 2   'check every 2nd value on sheet 1, col I
            If Len(col1(r1, 1)) > 0 And col1(r1, 1) <> "N/A" Then   'cell.sheet1 not empty
                found = (col1(r1, 1) = col2(r2, 1)) 'if c.sheet1 = c.sheet2 -> is found
                If found Then Exit For
            End If
        Next
        If Not found Then
            If miss Is Nothing Then
                Set miss = ws2.Cells(r2, COLUMN_2)
            Else
                Set miss = Union(miss, ws2.Cells(r2, COLUMN_2))
            End If
        End If
    Next
    miss.Interior.Color = red
End Sub
```

Comment: Paul, this works perfectly for what I need. Thank you. Is there any way, to easily change how far this code looks down on the second sheet? I have data underneath this table in the same rows that do not need this code performed on. My set ends at row 100 on sheet 2. If not, don't worry, I can work around it I believe.

Comment: Sure; I'll leave the answer as is because it's more generic, but for your case update `max2`: replace this line `max2 = ws2.Cells(tr, COLUMN_2).End(xlUp).Row` with this **`max2 = 100`**